# How can I implement a pointer arrow on a toolbar in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit, uitoolbar

I'm looking to implement a pointer arrow above the currently selected toolbar icon much like the design found in Reeder and Instacast:

[image: Instacast toolbar]

The pointer arrow should move across smoothly when another toolbar item is pressed.  I need to be able to choose which items cause the arrow to move, as featured in Instacast and Reeder, where only certain items change the arrow position.

Can I do this without too much overhead and a lot of UIKit subclassing?

Comment: Have you looked at [UITabBardelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)? You can get when tabs are changed and what they are changed to so you can do your logic and move a pointer there.

Comment: I would prefer to use a UIToolbar as I don't want a title for the buttons and don't like the look of the tab bar.  Also, how would I create the pointer so that the line of the toolbar doesn't continue over the pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be too bad: just take an image of the little triangle like you have in your question, and put it in a `UIImageView` that sits above the toolbar.

Then set it up so that when the `action:` for the relevant toolbar button is called, the `UIImageView` slides so that it's in the right place, with animation. Something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"TriangleAnimation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.25];
triangleImageView.frame = //new location here
[UIView commitAnimations];
```